# Allow only images in file upload form element in directory HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html, file-upload

**HTML Code**

```
<input  type="file" accept="image/*" multiple webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory id="fileURL"/>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
var files, 
file, 
extension,
sum,
input = document.getElementById("fileURL"),
output = document.getElementById("fileOutput"),
holder = document.getElementById("fileHolder")
sizeShow = document.getElementById("filesSize");

input.addEventListener("change", function (e) {

    files = e.target.files;
    output.innerHTML = "";
    sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) {
        file = files[i];
        extension = file.name.split(".").pop();
        if(extension=="jpg"||extension=="png"){
            var size = Math.floor(file.size/1024 * 100)/100;
            sum = size+sum;
            output.innerHTML += "<li class='type-" + extension + "'>"+file.webkitRelativePath + file.name + " (" +  size + "KB)</li>";
        }else{
           file.remove();
        }
    }
    if(sum<1024*1024){
        sizeShow.innerHTML = Math.floor(sum/1024*100)/100 + " MB";
    }else if(sum>1024*1024){
        sizeShow.innerHTML = Math.floor(sum/1024*1024*100)/100 + " GB";
    }
}, false);
```

How do i get just the image in the file upload? `accept="image/*"` doesn't work for directory.

This does work but the statement `file.remove()` doesn't work at all.
I guess the input:file is read-only.

How do i solve this?

Comment: Even if you did get this working, remember that file extensions do not necessarily indicate whether or not something is an image.  Even if they did, you are missing a few.  Even if you only wanted JPEG and PNG, you still need to add `.jpeg` to your extension list.

Comment: In Chrome, `input.files` is writable, but you can only set it to `FileList`s, which themselves *are* readonly (you cannot create one, nor can you do array-like manipulation on them). I guess you're out of luck.

Comment: @pimvdb : Yeah, but i seriously need it. 
But is there way to send just the selected files to the server?
Using simple else. That would solve the entire problem. :)

Comment: If you send manually through ajax, you would be able to. But not with native form submitting, apparently.

Comment: Can you please write the code that is really every cool.
I would appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `input.files` to a `FileList` (obtained from e.g. drag and drop), but you cannot create/modify a `FileList`. So you cannot modify the files of an input to e.g. only contain images.

What you can do, though, is uploading manually (through ajax), and only send files that have a type starting with `"image/"`. See http://jsfiddle.net/WM6Sh/1/.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var files = $(this).find("input").prop("files");
    var images = $.grep(files, function(file) {
        return file.type.indexOf("image/") === 0;  // filter out images
    });

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/", true);

    $(xhr).on("readystatechange", function(e) {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
            console.log("Done");
        }
    });

    var data = new FormData();
    $.each(images, function(i) {
        data.append(i, this);  // append each image file to the data to be sent
    });

    console.log(
        "Sending %d images instead of all %d files...",
        images.length,
        files.length
    );
    xhr.send(data);
});
```